# How to dynamically remove a comma and add the word and using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, text

I am using jQuery UI's drag and drop function and on 'drop' it appends the item to an `<ul>` element with a ',' after each item. For the last appeneded `<li>` how can I dynamically remove the comma and add the word `and` before the item?

I tried:

`$(#pot ul li:last-child).text().replace(/,/g, '');`

But this gave me no luck.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".flavours li" ).draggable({
        revert:true
    });

    $( "#pot ul" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui, flavours ) {
            $( "<li></li>" ).text(ui.draggable.text() + ',').appendTo(this);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to separate content and presentation, you could do it in pure CSS if you don't need to be compatible with IE8 :

```
#pot ul li:not(:last-child):after {
  content:",";
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/atazeh/1/edit)

To be more compatible, you could also do it afterwards using jQuery and the same selector :

```
$('ul li:not(:last-child)').append(',');
```

or you could define a class with jQuery :

```
$('ul li').each(function(){ // this can be called each time you change the list
  if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
     $(this).removeClass('notLast'); 
  } else {
     $(this).addClass('notLast'); 
  }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/atazeh/4/edit)

Comment: Excellent answer, @dystroy you are simply amazing.

Comment: @Adil Thanks for the compliment. Coming from an experienced user like you it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the selector in `quotes` and you have to assign the changed text back to element

```
$('#pot ul li:last-child').text($('#pot ul li:last-child').text().replace(/,/g, ''));
```

or

```
el = $('#pot ul li:last-child');
el.text(el.text().replace(/,/g, 'and'));
```

Comment: The only problem with this is, when I do it on drop, it assumes that every element is the last one even when I add new ones. What i need to do is also tell it the other elements are not last-child. Because, as the elements are added one by one, at one point every element is a last-child.

Comment: Where does that replace the last comma with `and`?